# Cannot do migrations in TypeORM with NestJS

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, database-migration

When I try to execute any migration command from TypeORM I always receive the same error message: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Y21f.png)
I've the dataSource script as is specified in the TypeORM documentation:

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import { DataSource, DataSourceOptions } from 'typeorm';

dotenv.config();

export const dataSourceOption: DataSourceOptions = {
  type: 'postgres',
  url: process.env.POSTGRES_URL,
  logging: false,
  synchronize: false,
  entities: ['src/**/*.entity{.js,.ts}'],
  migrations: ['src/database/migrations/*.ts'],
  migrationsTableName: 'migrations',
};

const AppDataSource = new DataSource(dataSourceOption);
export default AppDataSource;
```

I tried to execute a migration:generate command and generate a migration from my Entities but I always had the same problem.

Comment: can you provide your package.json file?

Comment: Sure, I added it as an answer